# Can I use glu with Android NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, glu

I can't seem to include *glu.h* in my Android NDK project.

I'm trying to port existing C++ code to NDK, and it uses glu in a few places (notably `gluErrorString`).

Does OpenGLES not have glu?

Is there a port I can use?

If not I can probably remove the calls to things like `gluPerspective` and so on, but what do I do about `gluErrorString`?

Comment: Was my answer useful for you or you would like to wait for another solution?

Comment: Sorry Idolon, that was rather rude or me but I've been busy. Fortunately it still lets me award the rep, and I have done so.

Comment: NP, we all have real life ;) That's why 24 hours grace period [has been added](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49830/158912) recently to the bounty system. Thanks for the rep.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Does OpenGL ES not have glu?

No, it doesn't. Look at this: [Platform OpenGL Includes collection](http://newcod.uberfinity.com/research/glincludes). Under Android there are only the following headers:

OpenGL ES 1.1:

```
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES/glext.h>
```

OpenGL ES 2.0:

```
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>
```

---

> Is there a port I can use?

Yes, there is a partial port of GLU for Android - [GLU ES](http://code.google.com/p/glues/) (it supports `gluErrorString`, `gluPerspective` and numerous other functions):

> **GLU 1.3 partitial port (libutil and libtess components only) for
>   OpenGL ES 1.x (CM - Common profile) and above.**
>
> This port supports:
>
> - Quadrics: gluNewQuadric(), gluDeleteQuadric(), gluQuadricCallback(),
>     gluQuadricNormals(), gluQuadricTexture(), gluQuadricOrientation(),
>     gluQuadricDrawStyle(), gluCylinder(), gluDisk(), gluPartialDisk(),
>     gluSphere().
> - Registry: gluGetString(), gluCheckExtension(),
>     **gluErrorString()**.
> - Projection matrix manipulation: gluOrtho2D(),
>     gluPerspective(), gluLookAt(), gluProject(), gluUnProject(),
>     gluUnProject4(), gluPickMatrix().  2D Mipmaps: gluScaleImage(),
>     gluBuild2DMipmapLevels(), gluBuild2DMipmaps().
> - Tesselation:
>     gluBeginPolygon(), gluDeleteTess(), gluEndPolygon(),
>     gluGetTessProperty(), gluNewTess(), gluNextContour(),
>     gluTessBeginContour(), gluTessBeginPolygon(), gluTessCallback(),
>     gluTessEndContour(), gluTessEndPolygon(), gluTessNormal(),
>     gluTessProperty(), gluTessVertex().

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good start. Doesn't build for android out of the box, but I should be able to pull out what I need. It annoys me slightly that there seems to be a glu for android java but not android ndk.

Comment: Can you help me "pull out what I need"? Specifically I just want to be able to draw quadrics - see my new SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27346503/using-glu-es-in-android