# Android openGL ES 2 floating point vs pixels

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to use openGL for 2D rendering. I have a basic function moving squares from one end of the screen to the other and repositioning them once they have gone off screen.

My problem is that I don't know how to get accurate representations of the screen in floating point values. Right now, -1.8f is the left side of my screen. I'm assuming this would only work for my own device. Am I correct?

How would I accurately find lets say, the bottom left of the screen?

Comment: The sides of the screen will depend in your projection and your modelview.

Comment: Is there an equation I can use for this?

Comment: Yes, but to save some math... : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300416/projection-of-square-onto-2d-plane-opengl-es2