# Using GLU ES in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, glu

so I want to draw simple shapes (cylinders, spheres, and cones) in my Android app. Based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589563/can-i-use-glu-with-android-ndk), it seems like it is possible to port GLU into Android, which has exactly those functions I need. However, I am having trouble getting it to compile. So far I have tried the following:

1. Download glues-1.4-bin-qnx.tar.gz from [the glues download page](http://code.google.com/p/glues/downloads/list)
2. Create a new module ("glues") in my Android project, with the include/ files from the download above and libGLUES_CM.a
3. Include this module in my jni/Android.mk

Here is my glues/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := glues
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/libGLUES_CM.a
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -IC:/usr/src/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include \
                -IC:/usr/src/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/sys
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

And my jni/Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := opengl
NDK_MODULE_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/..
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -I/usr/include
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := glues
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_wickhambros_charactercreator_OpenGlJniWrapper.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid -lGLESv2 -lGLESv1_CM -lEGL -lm

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/..)

$(call import-module,glues)
```

When I build, I get this error: **glues/include/glues.h:54:5: error: #error "Platform is unsupported"**

Answer (score 0):

[QNX](http://www.qnx.com/) is probably not what you want.

Instead you will need to compile the sources for Android. I managed almost to get it to compile by adding the following lines to the header files where it complains with "Platform is unsupported"

```
#elif defined (ANDROID)
  #include <GLES/gl.h>
  #include <GLES/glext.h>
  #define APIENTRY
  #define GLAPI
```

I failed on `GL_CLIENT_PIXEL_STORE_BIT` which is used in glues_mipmap.c and cannot be found in the android ndk.

It is well possible that your requirements are satisfied if you just build without this file.